# Kafka Source Connect - Column WhiteListing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Can we whitelist source columns in kafka connector instead of blacklisting columns? I am using kafka connect with debezium to fetch CDC changes from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot.

For SQL Server (and any relational connector), the databases, schemas, and tables can all be specified as a whitelist or blacklist configuration setting.  Unfortunately columns are only permissible as blacklists.

For MongoDB (non-relational connectors), the databases and collections can all be specified as a whitelist or blacklist configuration setting.  Unfortunately fields are only permissible as blacklists.

Comment: Naros , Thanks for your response. 
I need your advise in handling the source connector for relational DBs, where schema changes are taking place in our source. If any property can work in such case. I would like to hear back soon from you.

Comment: For schema evolution, please see https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html#schema-evolution